# Ссылка становится не кликабельна после добавления к ней обработчика

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться! Прописал простенький jquery для плавного скролинга по странице. Присвоил обработчик всем a-элементам блока навигации. Но одна из ссылок ведет на другую страницу и из-за скрипта она не кликабельна. Что можно сделать?

```
<div id="navigation">
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#top-section">начало</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">о нас</a></li>
<li><a href="price.html">цены</a></li>
<li><a href="#video">портфолио</a></li>
<li><a href="#contacts">контакты</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

---

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(){
var str=$(this).attr('href');
$.scrollTo(str,1000);
return false;
});
```

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#navigation a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
    var str=$(this).attr('href');
    $.scrollTo(str,1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: я предполагал что можно написать что-то подобное, но не знал как)) большое спасибо!

Comment: @ipshik, даже лучше будет вот так 

a[href^="#"]

Comment: а можно узнать какая разница между * и ^?

Comment: @ipshik `*` выбирает все элементы, в которых есть указанное значение в любой позиции, `^` - только те, которые с него начинаются.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_attribute.html#link4